# Random 504 Gateway Timeouts for Network Calls in Locally Served Angular App Using Webpack Dev Server Proxy

Tags: angular, azure, webpack-dev-server, azure-virtual-machine

We have an Angular app created using the Angular CLI, and it uses the Webpack dev server to proxy requests to a backend server hosted on an Azure VM.

The `proxy.config.json` file has the `changeOrigin` flag set to `true`, `secure` flag set to `false`, and `logLevel` set to `debug`.

The issue is that some of the network calls from Angular app, when served locally, randomly result in 504 Gateway Timeout errors.

1. Increased the timeout value in `proxy.config.json`.
2. Tried suggested config from angular documentation for application running behind [corporate proxy](https://angular.io/guide/build#using-corporate-proxy)

The gateway time outs are not observed when

1. Backend API is called from Postman without using the proxy server i.e. entering url of backend server instead of 127.0.0.1:4300/api
2. Backend server is healthy and responsive, and when the app deployed to same vm it works fine.

There are no specific patterns regarding the type of request that encounters the timeout.